# Check if record exists and autofill the id from mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

1. When user fills the form, if LinkedIn Id already exists, it should throw an error saying `LinkedIn Id already exists.`.
2. Form is not saving data if user does not enter `ContactID`. `ContactID` is an auto-increment field in MySQL table. Since more than one user works on the same form at the same time, I want `ContactID` to be auto-filled by the next available number from MySQL table.

Here, is my HTML form code and following, the PHP code. If you require any other details to debug, please ask.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="demo.php">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="contact_css.css">
<!--Create a table -->

<table>
<tr><td><b>Contact Information</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <div class="leftside">
  <td>ContactID</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="ContactID"></td>
 </div>
 <div class="rightside">
  <td>ContactOwner</td>
<!--  <td><input type="text" name="ContactOwner"></td>-->
    <td><select name="ContactOwner">
 <option value="None">None</option>
 <option value="Malik">Malik</option>
 <option value="Ankit">Ankit</option>
 <option value="Vikrant">Vikrant</option>
 </select></td>
 </div>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <div class="rightside">
  <td>LeadSource</td>
  <td><select name="LeadSource">
 <option value="None">None</option>
 <option value="Advertisement">Advertisement</option>
 <option value="ColdCall">ColdCall</option>
 <option value="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>

<option value="Web">Web</option>

 </select></td>
  <!--<td><input type="text" name="LeadSource"></td>-->
 </div>

<div class="leftside">
  <td>First_name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="First_name"></td>
 </div>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <div class="rightside">
 <td>Last_name</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="Last_name"></td>
 <td>AccountName</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="AccountName"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td>Title</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Title"></td>
   <td>EmailID</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="EmailID"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Industry</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Industry"></td>
  <td>Department</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Department"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Phone</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Phone" required></td>
  <td>Mobile</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Mobile"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <td>Today_date</td>
  <td><input type="date" name="Today_date"></td>

  <td>LinkedIn</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LinkedIn"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>CallStatus</td>
  <td><select name="CallStatus">
 <option value="None">None</option>
 <option value="AnsweringMachine">AnsweringMachine</option>
 <option value="Callback">Callback</option>
 <option value="NotInterested">NotInterested</option>
 <option value="Prospect">Prospect</option>
 <option value="WrongContact">WrongContact</option>
 <option value="PerformedInternally">PerformedInternally</option>
 <option value="LessThan30Employee">LessThan30Employee</option>
</select></td>
<td>Website</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Website"></td>

</tr>
  </table>

<!-- Second table-->
<table>
<tr><td><b>Address Information</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <div class="leftside">
  <td>Street</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Street"></td>
 </div>
 <div class="rightside">
  <td>OtherStreet</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="OtherStreet"></td>
 </div>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <div class="leftside">
  <td>City</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="City"></td>
 </div>
 <div class="rightside">
  <td>State</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="State"></td>
 </div>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Zip</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Zip"></td>
  <td>Country</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Country"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<!--Third table-->
<table>
<tr><td><b>Description Information</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Description</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Description" class="Description"></td>

 </table>
 <button type="button">Cancel</button>
 <button type="button" class="button2" onclick="window.location.href='fetch_data.php'"  />View</button>
 <button type="button" class="button3" onclick="window.location.href='exm_list.php'"  />Edit</button>
 <button type="submit">Add</button>

 </form>
 < /body>
 </html>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

// create a variable
if (isset($_POST)){

$ContactID=$_POST['ContactID'];
$ContactOwner=$_POST['ContactOwner'];
$LeadSource=$_POST['LeadSource'];
$First_name=$_POST['First_name'];
$Last_name=$_POST['Last_name'];
$AccountName=$_POST['AccountName'];
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$EmailID=$_POST['EmailID'];
$Industry=$_POST['Industry'];
$Department=$_POST['Department'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Mobile=$_POST['Mobile'];

$Today_date=$_POST['Today_date'];
$LinkedIn=$_POST['LinkedIn'];
$CallStatus=$_POST['CallStatus'];
$Website=$_POST['Website'];
$Street=$_POST['Street'];
$OtherStreet=$_POST['OtherStreet'];
$City=$_POST['City'];
$State=$_POST['State'];
$Zip=$_POST['Zip'];
$Country=$_POST['Country'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
}
//create connection 
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','contacts');
$check="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact where ContactID='$_POST[ContactID]' ";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$check);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
if($data[0] > 1){
echo "LinkedIn id already exists";
}
else {
$newUser="INSERT INTO contact(ContactID,ContactOwner,LeadSource,First_name,Last_name,AccountName,Title,EmailID,Industry,Department,Phone,Today_date,LinkedIn,CallStatus,Website,Street,OtherStreet,City,State,Zip,Country,Description)
            VALUES('$ContactID','$ContactOwner','$LeadSource','$First_name','$Last_name','$AccountName','$Title','$EmailID','$Industry','$Department','$Phone','$Today_date','$LinkedIn','$CallStatus','$Website','$Street','$OtherStreet','$City','$State','$Zip','$Country','$Description')";
if (mysqli_query($connect,$newUser))
{
    echo "Information Added<br/>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error adding user in database, ContactID exists.<br/>";
}
}
```

Comment: Please use [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$check="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact where ContactID='$_POST[ContactID]' ";
```

to

```
$check="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact where ContactID='$ContactID' ";
```

Also:

> Form is not saving data if user do not enters ContactID. *** ContactID
>   is an autoincrement field in mysql table.

In your insert do not include

```
ContactID,
```

since this is an autoincrement field as you mention. What you should do instead is to do this:

//create connection

```
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','contacts');
$check="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact where ContactID='$ContactID' ";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$check);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

if($data[0] > 1){
          echo "LinkedIn id already exists";
}else {

    $newUser="INSERT INTO contact(ContactOwner,LeadSource,First_name,Last_name,AccountName,Title,EmailID,Industry,Department,Phone,Today_date,LinkedIn,CallStatus,Website,Street,OtherStreet,City,State,Zip,Country,Description)
            VALUES('$ContactOwner','$LeadSource','$First_name','$Last_name','$AccountName','$Title','$EmailID','$Industry','$Department','$Phone','$Today_date','$LinkedIn','$CallStatus','$Website','$Street','$OtherStreet','$City','$State','$Zip','$Country','$Description')";
    if (mysqli_query($connect,$newUser))
    {
        echo "Information Added<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @JasmineLalani what happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: :The code you edited and shared, I tried to run it but it is not working as I require.i.e. if I do not enter "ContactID" ,the form is not being submitted,it throws an error "Error adding user in database, ContactID exists".I removed ContactID from insert statement

Comment: Did you follow this `$newUser="INSERT INTO contact(ContactOwner,LeadSource,First_name,Last_name,AccountName,Title,EmailID,Industry,Department,Phone,Today_date,LinkedIn,CallStatus,Website,Street,OtherStreet,City,State,Zip,Country,Description)
            VALUES('$ContactOwner','$LeadSource','$First_name','$Last_name','$AccountName','$Title','$EmailID','$Industry','$Department','$Phone','$Today_date','$LinkedIn','$CallStatus','$Website','$Street','$OtherStreet','$City','$State','$Zip','$Country','$Description')";`?

Comment: Also, note that you need to input a ContactID since it is being used in your `$check` variable